# Descargar imagen laravel

Tags: laravel, imagen, descarga

Tengo el siguiente enlace:

```
<a href="http://www.codigos-qr.com/barcode/barcode.processor.php?encode=CODE128&bdata={{$row->code}}w&height=40&scale=2&showData=1&Genrate=" title="Generar Codigo" target="_blank">{{ $row->code }}</a>
```

El mismo me genera un barcode en una url externa. ¿Hay alguna forma que en vez de abrir el enlace con la imagen, pueda descargarla directamente?

Comment: Podrias explicar mejor el problema?, veo en el ejempo que tienes un **link** de la imagen y lo que deseas es que la imagen se vea? porque no intentas algo como `<img src="http://www.codigos-qr.com/barcode/barcode.processor.php?encode=CODE128&bdata={{$row->code}}w&height=40&scale=2&showData=1&Genrate="/>`.

Comment: Al entrar al link me carga la imagen sin ningun problema. Solo necesito forzar la descarga directamente.

Comment: Listo, solucionado.

Comment: Podrias poner la solucion? seria de ayuda para otras personas.

Answer (score 1):

Hice la descarga automaticamente con curl. Anexo codigo.

```
$curlCh = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($curlCh, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($curlCh, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($curlCh, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3); 
$curlData = curl_exec ($curlCh); 
curl_close ($curlCh); 
$downloadPath = "uploads/codes/$code->code.png"; 
$file = fopen($downloadPath, "w+"); fputs($file, $curlData);       
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta función me permite obtener la imagen o archivo por url externa y guardarla en el storage del proyecto.
El nombre lo asignar por el id y conserva la extensión del archivo

la url externa de la imagen deber esta publicada en la web para que funcione

```
public function descagarImagenURL()
  {
    /*
    $data = [
      array('id' => 1, 'url' => 'https://img.freepik.com/foto-gratis/pintura-lago-montana-montana-al-fondo_188544-9126.jpg?w=1380&t=st=1707755258~exp=1707755858~hmac=22c253348e247ca888d8cedc848c142cdb0adfb0844ec0e7ce88830cf5942fd1'),
      array('id' => 2, 'url' => 'https://img.freepik.com/foto-gratis/pintura-lago-montana-montana-al-fondo_188544-9126.jpg?w=1380&t=st=1707755258~exp=1707755858~hmac=22c253348e247ca888d8cedc848c142cdb0adfb0844ec0e7ce88830cf5942fd1')
    ];
    */
    $data = \App\DescargaImagenModel::all(); //Modelo ['id', 'url' ]
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

      $nombre_file_url = substr($value['url'], strrpos($value['url'], "/") + 1);
      $extension = substr($value['url'], strrpos($value['url'], ".") + 1);
      $extension =  explode('?', $extension); //obtener la extension del archivo
      echo "$extension[0] <br>";
      echo "$nombre_file_url <br>";

      \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::disk('NoConformidadPDF')->put($value['id'] . '.' . $extension[0], file_get_contents($value['url']));
    }
  }
```